# How to setup alljoyn sdk in android?

Tags: android, alljoyn

I am trying to setup two android devices to communicate with each other through wifi.  Some of the links I have gone through suggest alljoyn sdk in order to accomplish this.

[There is an sdk download](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/download) but there is no documentation for how to setup environment.

Comment: Android has a socket support with both UDP and TCP. You can try using them without an external library to develop your programming as well.

Comment: ok thank you ...I will look into it . Is there any other way to communicate the above scenario .One more doubt what about network service discovery in android?

Comment: there is a complete doc over there about alljoyn.... check out the framework tutorial. @harish.ooty-flashtoandroid

Answer (score 20):

Here is how to set up an AllJoyn SDK development environment with android studio:

1. Download the SDK from [this page](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/download). Go for Android Core SDK - release (or debug).
2. Create a new blank android project.
3. Create directory `<project>/app/src/main/jniLibs` and `<project>/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi`.
4. From `alljoyn-15.09.00-rel/java/jar` copy *alljoyn.jar* and from `alljoyn-15.09.00-rel/java/lib` copy *liballjoyn_java.so*. The directory to copy from might differ depending on the current version and your release/debug choice.
5. Put *alljoyn.jar* in `/jniLibs` and put *liballjoyn_java.so* in `/jniLibs/armeabi`.   Should look like this

   [image]
6. Right click project -> Open Module Settings -> app -> Dependencies.
   With the green [+] button, add a file dependency. 
   [image]

   Navigate to `<project>/app/src/main/jniLibs/alljoyn.jar` and select that jar.

   This will add a line in your gradle (`compile files('src/main/jniLibs/alljoyn.jar')`) that will allow for code completion etc.
7. In the file where you want to use alljoyn code, include this snippet

   ```
   /* Load the native alljoyn_java library. */
   static {
       System.loadLibrary("alljoyn_java");
   }
   ```

   for example:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       /* Load the native alljoyn_java library. */
       static {
           System.loadLibrary("alljoyn_java");
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
8. You can now use the alljoyn SDK. Import classes with

   ```
   import org.alljoyn.bus.BusAttachment;
   import org.alljoyn.bus.BusException;
   import org.alljoyn.bus.BusListener;
   ```

   etc.

If you're more of an eclipse guy, check [this](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/api-guide/core/java) official documentation page on how to setup an eclipse environment.

Comment: **NOTE** for those who get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when trying to run it on Visual Studio Android Emulator. The emulator is x86, but AllJoyn SDK is ARM only. In other words, you can't use this emulator.