# INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE after adding alljoyn

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a chat in android studio using the alljoyn framework. I have followed the steps provided here 
[How to setup alljoyn sdk in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473151/how-to-setup-alljoyn-sdk-in-android)
to setup alljoyn in my project, but when i try to test my project I get the following error: INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE.
I need to point out that I did not get this error before setting up alljoyn. After I added the framework I received this error.

Answer (score 0):

That bug means you don't have the native libraries for the type of processor you're using.  If they're available, make sure to add the x86 and arm libraries.

Answer (score 0):

ABI stands for Application Binary Interface. This basically means the library uses native codes. This is architecture specific. So if the library is for arm, it won't work on x86. If its for x86 it won't work for arm. You can look for the these libraries and add them.