# Setting up alljoyn android studio

Tags: java, android, alljoyn

I am currently working on a chat using the alljoyn framework. I used the tutorial presented here [How to setup alljoyn sdk in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473151/how-to-setup-alljoyn-sdk-in-android) to set it up in my android project, but I keep on receiving the same error no matter what I try:

A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9142 (e.com.finaltest)

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you added  compile files('libs/alljoyn.jar')
    compile files('libs/alljoyn_apps_android_utils.jar')
    compile files('libs/alljoyn_about.jar') in buid.gradle

Comment: I only have compile files('src/main/jniLibs/alljoyn.jar') as it was presented in the tutorial I linked