# AllJoyn Compilation leads to UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, alljoyn

There's a problem whenever I build my project to my phone (Android 4.4.2).

I get the UnsatisfiedLinkError and it seems that the alljoyn library is not yet loaded.
The only thing that I've added is `static { System.loadLibrary("alljoyn_java"); }`
before the `onCreate()` method of the Main activity.

Here is the build.gradle file for reference:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "secret.secret.secret"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('src/main/java/jniLibs/alljoyn.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1lfa.png)
[Android Studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvY1x.png)

Maybe I'm using the wrong android sdk. What could be the problem? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473151/how-to-setup-alljoyn-sdk-in-android) except that I placed the jar file inside the `app/libs/` folder.

One good point that I see here is that the jar file can be anywhere but the .so file must be at the `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/`. I don't know the reason behind this -- can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

The `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/` location is the default one. You can specify a custom location adding:

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'your/custom/location' 
}
```

to

```
android {
   ...
}
```